# how closely does vim search and replace follow regex?

Tags: regex, search, vim, replace, substitution

how strictly does vim search and vim substitute follow regex?  For example, this is a whole word search in regex:

```
\bwordtofind\b
```

but in vim normal mode, this command does NOT work:

```
/\bwordtofind\b
```

but some regex commands do work, for example, non-word barrier escape '\W' does work, ie:

```
/\Wwordwithnonwordcharssurroundingit/W
```

Why the inconsistency?  Help me understand the logic behind vim search and vim substitute.

Comment: but why is not consistent with regex?  that is my question.

Comment: i see that vim reserves '\b' for 'backspace'.  I guess vim doesn't offer a distinction between ASCII character escaping and regex instructions in the even they have the same instruction.  In regex, you can make a distinction between the two...

Comment: There is no such thing as a "one true regex syntax", there are at least 50 different dialects in common use.  Vim implements a pretty rich one, but which is not compatible to Perl and Python regexes.  You really should read `:h pattern`, it shall save you from a lot of hair pulling.